# correct implementation of datasource pagination

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So at first page it shows the corrrect display

[image]

---

But when I click next page it is displaying , it it displaying 21-20 of , which is wrong.

[image]

[image]

#html code that uses the component add passes the prefix text and suffix text

```
<app-table-paginator-text [dataSource]="dataSource" [prefixText]="'Showing'" [suffixText]="'results'"></app-table-paginator-text>
```

#data source html code

```
<div id="table-paginator-text" class="secondary-text" *ngIf="dataSource.paginator !== undefined">
  {{prefixText}} {{(dataSource.paginator.pageIndex === 0)? 1: (dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex) + 1 }} - {{this.dataSource.connect().value.length}} of {{dataSource.data.length}} {{suffixText}}      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data source code, you are correctly offsetting the left-hand number by the pageSize, but the right-hand side is simply the length of the current set. You need to add the offset there, too. I think the following should do it:

```js
(dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex) + this.dataSource.connect().value.length
```

Comment: do you mean I have to replace all of this {{(dataSource.paginator.pageIndex === 0)? 1: (dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex) + 1 }} - {{this.dataSource.connect().value.length}} of {{dataSource.data.length}} with the code you provided Sir?

Comment: No, you only need to replace `this.dataSource.connect().value.length`

Comment: can you post the completed one ? based on my code above

Comment: `{{(dataSource.paginator.pageIndex === 0)? 1: (dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex) + 1 }} - {{(dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex) + this.dataSource.connect().value.length}} of {{dataSource.data.length}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div id="table-paginator-text" class="secondary-text" *ngIf="dataSource.paginator !== undefined">
  {{prefixText}} {{(dataSource.paginator.pageIndex === 0)? 1: (dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex + 1)}} - {{dataSource.paginator.pageSize * dataSource.paginator.pageIndex + this.dataSource.connect().value.length}} of {{dataSource.data.length}} {{suffixText}}      
</div>
```